# URI manipulation in .NET compact framework

Tags: .net, url, compact-framework, uri

What's the best way to manipulate URIs in .NET compact framework?  I basically need to load up a URL string, then allow the user to change the "Scheme" and "Host" values.  I've been using the Uri class so far, but it's essentially immutable, so you can't really modify any of the components of the Uri, once it's initialized.

The UriBuilder looked like it would be the best solution, but it does not seem to exist in the compact framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an alternative to UriBuilder, that exists in the compact framework. Your best bet would probably be to create your own UriBuilder with the functionality you need, for use in the compact framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `UrlBuilder` class from CodeProject :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UrlBuilder.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it looks like that inherits from UriBuilder though.